# Can a real plane curve have a singular complex point but no singular real points?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, singularity, real-algebraic-geometry

Let $p(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}[x,y]$. Is it possible that $\partial_xp(x,y)=\partial_yp(x,y)=p(x,y)=0$ has a solution $(x,y)\in\mathbb{C}^2$ but no solutions $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$?

In other word, can you see if a real curve is "smooth" just by looking at the real points?

Of course, one could ask similar questions about arbitrary varieties over an arbitrary field $k$ (with $\mathbb{C}$ replaced by the algebraic closure $\bar{k}$): can a variety $X$ over $k$ be smooth at all $k$-points but have a singular $\bar{k}$-point, and if so, are there nice conditions (on $k$ or $X$) which make this impossible?

Comment: Consider $p(x,y) = \frac13 x^3 + x - (\frac13 y^3 + y)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure.  For a simple example, take $p(x,y)=(x^2+1)(y^2+1)$.  This has no real points at all, but has singular complex points at $(\pm i,\pm i)$.  (This example can immediately be generalized to any non-algebraically closed field, by letting $p(x,y)=q(x)q(y)$ where $q$ is a polynomial with no roots in the base field.  Or, if you want to require $p$ to be squarefree, this works as long as the field is not separably closed.  I don't know an irreducible example off the top of my head but I expect it is possible.)

Comment: For an irreducible example, the trick is to take a double cover with non-simple branch points that are strictly complex. At first I tried to do this with an elliptic curve, but to keep coefficients in $\mathbb R$ it seems that we have to introduce all phenomena in conjugate pairs. So let $f(x) = (x-i)^2(x+i)^2 = (x^2 + 1)^2$ and look at the curve $y^2 = f(x)$. This has nodes at $(\pm i, 0)$ and nowhere else, but the defining polynomial is $y^2 - (x^2+1)^2 \in \mathbb R[x,y]$.